# Why does not the string equal to a text value in sqlite3 database (Python)

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter, sqlite

hi i am trying to make a simple login module in tkinter for that i am taking input from the user via the entry widget and comparing that password to the password in database via a if loop... but for some reason the password doesnt match, so i tried some tests and it dosent match ....

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('auth_rWebsites.db')
c=conn.cursor()

def check_password(key):
    thePass= c.execute("SELECT pass FROM user_pass") 
    if key == thePass:
        print("right Password")
    else:
        print("Wrong Password")

rows= c.execute("SELECT * FROM user_pass")
for row in rows:

    print row

check_password("root")
```

this the above simple test code i wrote..
output is

```
(u'root',)
Wrong Password
```

so someone please explain me why is this happening and what do i have to do to match it ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thePass` is an iterable that yeilds `tuple`s, `key` is a string.

In general, the python db api always returns database rows as tuples because you can select multiple things in a statement.  Rather than having confusing logic that needs to look at the query to determine the return type of the row (for both the database api and the caller), the spec says to just return a tuple always.

You need to compare `key` with the row correctly...

```
rows = c.execute("Select pass FROM user_pass")
for row in rows:
    if row[0] == thePass:
        print("right password")
        return
else:
    print("Wrong Password")
```

Note, this probably isn't what you actually want.  All it does is verify that one row in the `user_pass` table has that `pass` value.  More likely, you want to filter the query against the username and then check the password:

```
c.execute("SELECT pass FROM user_pass WHERE username = ?", username)
result = c.fetchone()  # username should be unique I assume :-)
if result[0] == salt_and_hash(key):
    print("Yeah!")
else:
    print("No!")
```

Answer (score 3):

`c.execute("SELECT pass FROM user_pass")` is returning a tuple, not a string, but `key` is a string. You need to get the first value from the tuple and compare that to your `key` argument, so change your function to this:

```
def check_password(key):
    thePass= c.execute("SELECT pass FROM user_pass")[0] # Changed here
    if key == thePass:
        print("right Password")
    else:
        print("Wrong Password")
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is correct... Won't `c.execute` return an iterable that yields tuples?